# Powershell Script run by Scheduled Tasks, presenting regional settings issue

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, splunk, regional-settings

I have a Powershell script that collects hostname and latency information from some virtual machines. When collecting the latency the digit separator must be ".".

If I run the script with a normal user, it shows "." as the digit separator printed on the screen after the command. But when I put a scheduled task to run it, the values come separated by ",". Even when I run it to be exported to a file...

Normal User:
Server923                   cpu.latency.average                             0.02
Server836                   cpu.latency.average                             0.04

System User:
Server923                   cpu.latency.average                             0,02
Server836                   cpu.latency.average                             0,04

I have changed the regional settings back and forth, copied it to all users, new users and system users, also removed all additional keyboards (and kept EN-US only), and rebooted a few times. The behavior persists.

Windows Server 2012 @English

How do I solve this?

Comment: Under what user are you running the scheduled task ? The same as the one you changed regional settings for ? Or under NT AUTHORITY\System ?

Comment: I just found out that there is a specific user that runs the job to run the scheduled task, so a "whoami" command in the script showed that its being run by a generic domain user. I just deleted (removed completely) the user profile and rebooted, it was created again, now being forced to inherit the default regional settings, and it WORKED!

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that there is a specific user that runs the job to run the scheduled task, so a "whoami" command in the script showed that its being run by a generic domain user. I just deleted (removed completely) the user profile and rebooted, it was created again, now being forced to inherit the default regional settings, and it WORKED!